# Hostname not verified Android

Tags: android, ssl, https, httpsurlconnection

I'm using *HttpsUrlconnection* for connections to my webapp which is hosted on a shared hosting plan. I'have noticed that everything's working fine unless the sky is cloudy (or , for the rare times that it has happened, unknown reasons), then throws a:

```
 java.io.IOException: Hostname "url" was not verified
```

I have searched in the internet for fixes in case that happens again, so i can think of an alternative solution, but all i found is replacing the HostnameVerifier which is dangerous.

Can anyone suggest me a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: You are not using an Android device before 2.3, don't you?

Comment: No, i'm not. My android app works on 3.0+ , i'm currently testing it on jelly bean

Comment: Have you checked that it is really an Android problem? May the shared hoster is simply unstable? use a PC based test tool that polls the url every minute or so.